# wordpress output var in template that is defined by admin-pages

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I'm new to wordpress. Is it possible to define a variable inside the pages-admin area?

I got an if-else statement in my template. It creates a text-output. But i don't want to define this text hard coded inside the template-file. I use polylang-plugin for multi-language support. So I'd like to set up a page for each language, which should define its own $msg text. 
Otherwise I'd need to check the languages inside the template to define the correct message in here - or use an extra template for each language. I don't beleave, that this is the only solution.

I'm looking for something like this ->
in template.php:

```
if (empty($statement)) {
    echo $msg1;
}
```

in admin-pages something like:

```
$msg1 = "no entries found";
```

how do I define vars outside the template-file?

Comment: hooks and filters - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks

Answer (score 0):

You can define variables within your [theme functions file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) (functions.php) or a [custom plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). You can take advantage of these via [hooks and filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) within WordPress core and your theme if it is supported. Here's an example using functions.php.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_var');
function my_custom_var() {
        $my_var = 'something different'
        echo $my_var;
    }
```

This will insert the echoed variable into any template file that uses `the_content`. Although very basic, this functionality will give you plenty of flexibility.

Comment: WP does not feature a `the_content` action hook.

Comment: @diggy thank you, you are correct. I replaced with add_filter